# AngularJS - Multiple controllers with GET requests, how to handle URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

The layout I have in mind involves two partials, each taking up half the page.

The left half will initially have a form to filter a query, and the JSON returned will be used to create markers on a Google Map which then fills the left half.

The right half will initially have text to instruct to user. Upon clicking a marker on the left half, the right half will be replaced by details associated with that marker from another JSON.

I'm very inexperienced with using Angular, so I may have some misconceptions. I've run into this problem: The left side needs the query in the URL, and the right side needs the marker ID in the URL. I don't have a clear idea of how to implement this layout, so I don't know what the URL structure would look like.

`www.website.com/mapview/ID/query` doesn't seem logical; it would be a last resort and I don't know what implications it may have. I also thought about POSTing the filter options, but that wouldn't allow users to bookmark their search, and the form re-submission warning would be very unexpected for users.

If this is possible to build, what's the cleanest solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need two different routes.

Using [Ui.Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router):

Keep in mind, each child route can inherit views, resolves, params, ecc from its parent(s).

```js
angular
  .module('test', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    
    var index = {
      name: 'mapview',
      url: '/mapview/:query/',
      abstract: true,
      views: {
        "left": {},
        "right": {}
      }
    };
    
    var one = {
      name: 'mapview.marker',
      url: ':markerId/',
      views: {
        "left@": {},
        "right@": {}
      }
    };
    var two = {
      name: 'mapview.nomarker',
      url: '',
      views: {
        "left@": {},
        "right@": {}
      }};

  
    $stateProvider.state(index).state(one).state(two);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been reading more about this, and it looks like this layout isn't as difficult as I thought it would be. What do you know about Angular new router, and how does it compare to ui-router?

Comment: This should be "another topic", by the way, the new Angular Router, in my opinion, brings a lot from Ui.Router and from the experiences around routing in AngularJS. But is totally different the approach chosed :)...
________________
https://medium.com/angularjs-meetup-south-london/angular-just-another-introduction-to-ngnewrouter-vs-ui-router-72bfcb228017

Comment: I see, so it isn't actually released yet. It was confusing because there are discussions of people using New Router in Angular 1.4, but at the same time there are sources saying that it will be released in 1.5 which obviously hasn't been released yet.

Another thing, why do we write the states in variables? Is that for re-usability, or personal preference? Thanks.

Comment: It's mostly for my preference, consider that local variables will be destroyed when their scope has no more reference (at the end of the config execution in this case)... By the way, using variable allows you to access into them if you need: one.name = index.name + '.marker';